Issue with solving merge conflict on pr in bitbucket
Context: I have a feature branch based on a main branch. Now I created a pr in bitbucket to merge my feature in the main branch and there's a conflict.
To resolve the merge conflict, I thought it logical to merge the main into my branch locally to resolve the conflicts with my editor and then push this again to my branch. SO, the conflict is resolved and bitbucket can merge my branch with main.
However, I am here because the following also happened to the pr because of it and I wonder whether it is expected behavior or a one time issue I faced:
The last time I did this. All changes made to the main branch since I based my feature branch on it, suddenly got added to the list of changes in the pr. This results in the lack of overview on my changes for reviewers and a scary large pr to review with things I didn't touch.
I expected for the merge conflict to be solved but without it adding all these changes made to the main branch on files I never even touched myself.
Was this a bug? Did I perhaps miss a step? Or is this actually expected behavior?

So are you using the same branch repeatedly for multiple PRs?

No, when the feature is merged into main, the feature branch is done.

Were you merging to the same branch you merged to your branch?

Yes. In bitbucket pr I merge my feature branch into the main branch. This causes conflict. So locally I solve the conflict by merging the main branch into my feature branch. Then this gets pushed for the pr conflict to be solved.

Judging by the comments showing signs of disbelief. I am guessing this is not expected behavior and likely a bug that can occur? Possibly the cause was the feature branch being far behind the main branch. That's the only cause I can imagine that makes my situation different from others.
